# Is moving to another Activity and start a service is possible? Android studio App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm tring to start a service and open a new activity, so the new activity's objects will always do what they do even if I clode my phone.

I have tried something like this:

In order to start the service, I wrote in MainActivity:
`startService(new Intent(this, FirstService.class));`

In First Service I wrote:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class FirstService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent, 0);

        return START_STICKY; // service will start

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { //stop the music
        super.onDestroy();
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, 0);

    }
}
```

Is doing that even possible?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible

From inside the Service class:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```